# Error message when integrating serenity with cucumber4

Tags: cucumber-serenity

Im trying to integrate Cucumber feature files with Serenity. When I run my tests using `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` they run fine, but when I change it to `@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)` raise an error.

Ive been following John Ferguson Smart's article here https://johnfergusonsmart.com/getting-started-with-serenity-bdd-and-cucumber-4/

My pom file:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF- 
 8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <serenity.version>2.0.41</serenity.version>
    <serenity.jbehave.version>1.44.0</serenity.jbehave.version>
    <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
    <cucumber.version>4.2.6</cucumber.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber4</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-report-resources</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-test-utils</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-jira-requirements-provider</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-jira-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-junit</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.52</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>0.22.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcabi-log</artifactId>
        <version>0.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.327</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.2.jre7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Cucumber-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Cucumber-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                <includes>

                    <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>

                </includes>
                <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver} . 
 </webdriver.driver>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Produced error message:

```
ava.lang.NoSuchMethodError: cucumber.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier.<init>(Lcucumber/runtime/model/FeatureLoader;Lcucumber/runtime/RuntimeOptions;)
```

Comment: Make sure the version numbers match those used in the tutorial . Looks like your cucumber version is too high.